# Find minimum and maximum value for each group based on another variable in R

Tags: r

I would like to know how I can find the minimum and maximum day of year (`DoY`) based on water temperature (`Wtemp`) for each site (`siteID`).

Example Dataset:

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 20))
x <- c("siteID", "Date", "DoY", "Wtemp")
colnames(df1) <- x
df1$siteID <- c(101,101,101,101,101,
                102,102,102,102,102,
                103,103,103,103,103,
                104,104,104,104,104)
df1$Date <- rep(seq(from = as.Date("2020-01-01"), to = as.Date("2020-01-05"), by = 1),4)  
df1$DoY <- rep(seq(from = 1, to = 5, by = 1),4) 
df1$Wtemp <- c(10,2,6,12,15,
               20,15,5,10,16,
               2,4,6,8,10,
               12,14,16,18,20)
```

The output should look like this:

```
  siteID DoY_MaxWtemp DoY_MinWtemp
1    101            5            2
2    102            1            3
3    103            5            1
4    104            5            1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can group by 'siteID', get the index of 'max' and 'min' value of 'Wtemp' with `which.max` and `which.min` respectively, use that to extract the corresponding values of 'DoY' in `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(siteID) %>% 
   summarise(Doy_MaxWtemp = DoY[which.max(Wtemp)],
            Doy_MinWtemp = DoY[which.min(Wtemp)], .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  siteID Doy_MaxWtemp Doy_MinWtemp
#*  <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
#1    101            5            2
#2    102            1            3
#3    103            5            1
#4    104            5            1
```